# Failed to execute 'removeChild' while component is unmounting

Tags: reactjs

I am currently integrating a video chat where people can switch between different rooms. That part works well. Now I want to add an additional components. If I click on "another component" while loading the Daily component I get the error:

> Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is
>   not a child of this node.

Video example of bug: https://www.loom.com/share/e9b03203fe42458f8b0abd44d250517b

I created the following Sandbox to demonstrate the problem: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-blackburn-oorng?file=/src/App.js

The problem seems to be connected with `dailyRef.current.destroy();`. And that it can't be executed if the video isn't in a "loaded finished" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an implementation of `daily.destroy` method

```js
 async destroy() {
    try {
      "joined-meeting" === this._meetingState && (await this.leave());
    } catch (t) {}
    let t = this.iframe();
    if (t) {
      let e = t.parentElement;
      e && e.removeChild(t);
    }
    window.removeEventListener("message", this._messageListener);
  }
```

You can extract from that necessary bits and only cleanup event listener

```
  return () => {
    try {
      "joined-meeting" === daily._meetingState && (await daily.leave());
    } catch (t) {}

    window.removeEventListener("message", daily._messageListener);
};
```